# Where to find all program icons?

Tags: 11.04, themes, icons

Using 11.04 and want to change the main menu (slim it way down).

Before doing that I'd like to place the icons/shortcuts of the programs I use very seldom into a desktop folder (only keeping those used very often in the menu).

Once before I was able to find a huge list of everything (via Nautilus ?), but I cannot find it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application icons can be found in the directory `/usr/share/applications`

To remove them from the dash menu, you'll need to delete them. But, I would recommend moving them to another directory for backup, just to be safe.